# Want to create XML element on the fly

Tags: xquery

I want to create an element on the fly, I'm trying below query but its giving me this error: `SQL16031N  XQuery language feature using syntax "element {$first} { "Crockett" }, element last {"Johnson" } } })" is not supported`

Could you please help me out.

```
    XQUERY
let $first := concat('first','')
return (element book { 
    attribute isbn {"isbn-0060229357" }, 
    element title { "Harold and the Purple Crayon"},
    element author { 
        element {$first} { "Crockett" }, 
        element last {"Johnson" }
    }
})
```

Comment: The error code seems to be from [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql16031n.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let $first := xs:QName('first')
return (element book { 
    attribute isbn {"isbn-0060229357" }, 
    element title { "Harold and the Purple Crayon"},
    element author { 
        element {$first} { "Crockett" }, 
        element last {"Johnson" }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Dave,
Its giving me similar type of error:   
SQL16031N  XQuery language feature using syntax "element {$first} { "Crockett" }, element last {"Johnson" } } })       " is not supported.

Comment: Hi Dave, Could you please let me know how can I use the above syntax to create element, as its giving me not supported error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DB2 XQuery doesn't support [computed element constructors](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrcmpelcn.html) with a dynamically computed name. If the number of possible names is small and known in advance, you can get around that limitation by listing all the possibilities. As DB2 doesn't seem to support `switch` either, we'll have to do it with an `if`/`else` cascade:

```
XQUERY
let $first := 'firstA'
return (element book { 
    attribute isbn {"isbn-0060229357" }, 
    element title { "Harold and the Purple Crayon"},
    element author { 
        if($first eq 'firstA')
          then element firstA { "Crockett" }
        else if($first eq 'firstB')
          then element firstB { "Crockett" }
        else if($first eq 'firstC')
          then element firstC { "Crockett" }
        else (), 
        element last {"Johnson" }
    }
})
```